# Pass object of class type to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might seem very trivial, but I cannot figure this out. In OOP language like c#, I can pass instance of self type to a function. For example,

```
class Edge 
{
void F(Edge e){
// Do something here.
}
}
```

Here function F takes an argument of type Edge, to which it belongs.

However, I am unable to do this in python.

```
class Edge:

    def f(self, that: Edge):
        pass
```

I get an error,

NameError: name 'Edge' is not defined

Can anyone point out how to get this working?

Thank you.

Comment: What for? That information is accessible within the class.

Comment: I want to pass an object of the same type and use this object variables to compare with the value of current instance. Something like compareTo in c#